# What is the best loop to use

Tags: php

I have some code that needs to loop through some code, but I am not sure what would be the best loop to use. The idea is, if there are any results from query then echo the ERROR: and stop. If there re no results then go to `bla bla`.

At the moment, the if statement is only returning 1 item and there are several. Now I know I need some type of loop to cycle through results, but need help with which loop to use. I have tried putting the if statement into the while loop, but it also goes straight to `bla bla`. I have also tried to use exit; in loop but this also fails.

I would be grateful if someone could help me with this as I am quite new to this form of coding. Many thanks

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM files WHERE department = '$dept' AND boxref = '$items'";
   $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
     if($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
         if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                $fileid = $row['id'];
                $fstatus = $row['filestatus'];
                $fitem = $row['custref'];
                $boxitem = $row['boxref'];
              }
            }
           }

          if($fstatus != '9') {
            echo 'ERROR:';
            echo ' File: ' . ' ' . $fitem . ' ' . ' In box: ' . $boxitem . '<br />';
          } else { 
            echo 'bla bla';
          }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by checking conditions after loop! You need to move statement into loop. Also you can remove *`mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0`*, because it doen't have any effect. (If you have no line, loop will be skipped)

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM files WHERE department = '$dept' AND boxref = '$items'";
   $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
     if($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
              $fileid = $row['id'];
              $fstatus = $row['filestatus'];
              $fitem = $row['custref'];
              $boxitem = $row['boxref'];
              if($fstatus != '9') {
                  echo 'ERROR:';
                  echo ' File: ' . ' ' . $fitem . ' ' . ' In box: ' . $boxitem . '<br />';
              } else { 
                  echo 'bla bla';
              }
        }
   }
```

I think that best loop throught rows is this loop - you don't have to thinking about something else.

Comment: Problem is that it is not stopping at the !=9 part but also printing 'bla bla', How do I halt the script if there are any results? Would exit be suitable?

Comment: @user1532468 If you want to skip loop only, add `break;` after "error" echo. If you want end whole php script set `die("Error message");` isted of "error" echo.

Comment: Thank you for that

Answer (score 2):

Hi use foreach loop its good for looping array of items:

Comment: $arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
foreach ($arr as &$value) {
    $value = $value * 2;
}

Comment: Thanks. What is the purpose of '&$value' the & here

Comment: If you want to learn more things on foreach in php search for "php foreach" in google, Click first link which should be php official link.